# Syntactic sugar to add variable-size element lists to vector?

Tags: c++, vector, syntactic-sugar

I have a class that contains a vector:

```
class Foo {
  typdef std::vector<int> Vec;
  Vec m_kids;
  void addKids(Vec::const_iterator begin, 
               Vec::const_iterator end) {
    m_kids.insert(m_kids.end(), begin, end);
  }
};
```

Is there any way to allow the following concise function calls? (Maybe by changing the `addKids` function above?)

```
int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.addKids(23,51,681);             // these...
  foo.addKids(3,6,1,4,88,2,4,-2,101); // ...would be nice?!
}
```

I suspect you can do it with C++0x vector initializer lists? But unfortunately, I cannot use C++0x. I can use Boost, though, if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Foo foo;
foo << 3, 6, 1, 4, 88, 2, 4, -2, 101; //inserts all!
```

For that you've to overloaded `<<` and `,` operators, as:

```
class Foo {
  typdef std::vector<int> Vec;
  Vec m_kids;
public:
  Foo& operator<<(int item) {
    m_kids.push_back(item); return *this;
  }
  Foo& operator,(int item) {
    m_kids.push_back(item); return *this;
  }
};
```

Once you implement this, then you can also write:

```
foo << 3 << 6 << 1 << 4 << 88 << 2 << 4 << -2 << 101; //inserts all!
```

Even this,

```
foo, 3, 6, 1, 4, 88, 2, 4, -2, 101; //inserts all!
```

Or mix both as:

```
foo << 3, 6, 1 << 4, 88, 2 << 4 << -2, 101; //inserts all!

//and this too!
foo,3 << 6, 1 << 4, 88, 2 << 4 << -2, 101; //inserts all!
```

All are same!

But mixing doesn't look good. My preference is the very first one!

Comment: That is clever! Overloading `operator,` was just for compability with his desired syntax I guess? As you've written it, `foo << 3 << 6 ...` would work, right?

Comment: +1 This is one approach present in the `boost::assign` library, I don't like it, but just as a matter of taste (It is the overloading of `operator,` that I dislike). Alternatively, the CORBA mapping for C++ uses overloads of `operator=<<` for an similar purpose, just as ugly (if not more) than the `<<`, but less likely to be confused with insertion into a stream.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% the same syntax, but check out boost's list_of: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any boost functionality that does this (most likely just because I haven't seen it yet, "boost has it" is almost an axoim...), but you could define a variadic function that does it. It'd look something like this:

```
void addKids(int N, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int val = va_arg(args, int);
        m_kids.push_back(val);
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Just a remark, the syntax won't be exactly the same, since `N` is the number of elements. So, for your examples, it'd be `foo.addKids(3, 23,51,681);` and `foo.addKids(9,3,6,1,4,88,2,4,-2,101);`

Comment: While I know variadics aren't exactly good, modern c++, it _does_ work... -1 for not kosher?

Comment: Another limitation of this approach is that the variable arguments in C++03 can only be used with fundamental types (and only a subset of them, IIRC)

Comment: Fundamental types, such as `int`s, as was asked for. I wholeheartedly agree that using `va_*` isn't the optimal solution from many points of view, but it _does_ solve the problem as stated, and does it with minimal change of syntax from what was desired. That said, I'd probably ditch similar syntax for all the niceities of overloading `operator<<` as Nawaz proposed.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your iterator types

```
template<typename T>
void addKids(T begin, T end)
{
  m_kids.insert(m_kids.end(), begin, end);
}
```

then you can at least do this:

```
int kids={1,2,3,4};
foo.addKids(kids,kids+4);
```

Which seems pretty concise.